# How to persist the value of a custom field on the customer_entity table?

Tags: customer-attribute, resource-model, custom-field, repository, after-plugin

I'm new to Magento 2 and to this forum.
I'm trying to add a newsletter subscription on the customer menu, just after the core one.

For that, i created a module "ACME_Newsletter"

1. I added a custom field to the customer_entity table via a db_schema :

   ```
    <table name="customer_entity">
    <column
        xsi:type="boolean"
        name="acme_nl_subscription"
        nullable="false"
        default="false"
        comment="Acme Newsletter Subscription"
    />
   ```
2. I created a layout that completes the existing one "customer_newsletter"

```
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_newsletter">
            <container name="customer.form.newsletter.extra">
                <block
                    class="ACME\Newsletter\Block\Subscription"
                    name="customer_form_newsletter_extra" as="acme_nl_subscription"
                    template="ACME_Newsletter::customer/form/subscription.phtml"
                />
            </container>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```

Here is my template :

```
    <?php

/** @var \ACME\Newsletter\Block\Subscription $block */
?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.newsletter.extra') ?>
<div class="field choice">
    <input type="checkbox" name="acme_nl_subscription" id="acme_nl_subscription" value="1"
           title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('ACME\'s Newsletter Subscription')) ?>"
        <?php if ($block->getCustomerSession()->getCustomer()->getAcmeNlSubscription()) : ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?>
           class="checkbox">
    <label for="acme_nl_subscription"
           class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('ACME\'s Newsletter Subscription')) ?></span></label>
</div>
```

And my block :

```
    <?php

namespace ACME\Newsletter\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Block\Newsletter;

class Subscription extends Newsletter
{
    public function getCustomerSession()
    {
        return $this->customerSession;
    }

}
```

With all that I manage to retrieve the value stored in database.

Now I try to modify that value and to store it in db, within an after plugin on the Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Manage\Save::execute() method.

I can't find the right way to write my method to persist this data.
For the moment, my plugin looks like this :

```
<?php

namespace ACME\Newsletter\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Manage\Save;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository as CustomerRepository;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer as CustomerResource;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer as CustomerModel;

class AfterSavePlugin
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $request;
    protected $customerRepository;
    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;
    protected $customerResource;
    protected $customerModel;

    public function __construct(
        Session                     $customerSession,
        RequestInterface            $request,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
        CustomerRepository          $customerRepository,
        CustomerResource            $customerResource,
        CustomerModel               $customerModel
    )
    {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->customerResource = $customerResource;
        $this->customerModel = $customerModel;
    }

    public function afterExecute(Save $subject, $result)
    {
        $acmeNlSubscription = $this->request->getParam('acme_nl_subscription') ? (bool)$this->request->getParam('acme_nl_subscription') : 0;

        $sessionCustomer = $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
        $customerData = $sessionCustomer->getData();

        $repositoryCustomer = $this->customerRepository->getById($sessionCustomer->getId());

//        $modelCustomer->loadByEmail($sessionCustomer->getEmail());
        $modelCustomer = $this->customerModel;
        $modelCustomer->setData($customerData);

        $resourceCustomer = $this->customerResource->loadByEmail($modelCustomer, $modelCustomer->getEmail());

        $modelCustomer->save();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Could a kind soul help me to take a step in my understanding of Adobe Commerce 2 (Magento 2) please?

What am I doing wrong? All comments are welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution by adding a Data Patch

```
<?php

namespace ACME\Newsletter\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

class AddSubscriptionColumn implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var SetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetup
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        SetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $setupCustomer */
        $setupCustomer = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerEntity = $setupCustomer->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $defaultAttributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet Set */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($defaultAttributeSetId);

        $setupCustomer->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'acme_nl_subscription',
            [
                'type' => 'static',
                'label' => 'Acme Newsletter Subscription',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => 0,
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $setupCustomer->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'acme_nl_subscription');
        $attribute->addData([
            'used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'checkout_register',
                'customer_account_create',
                'newsletter_manage',
                'newsletter_manage_save'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $defaultAttributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId
        ]);
        $attribute->save();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * Rollback all changes
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $setupCustomer */
        $setupCustomer = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $setupCustomer->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'acme_nl_subscription');
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

}
```

The latest version of my method AfterSavePlugin::afterExecute()

```
    public function afterExecute(Save $subject, $result)
    {
        try {
            $acmeNlSubscription = $subject->getRequest()->getParam('acme_nl_subscription') ? $subject->getRequest()->getParam('acme_nl_subscription') : 0;

            $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomerId();

            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);

            $customer->setAcmeNlSubscription($acmeNlSubscription);

            $this->customerRepository->save($customer->getDataModel());

        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->logger->error($exception->getMessage());
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

If anyone can explain to me why this is necessary to create a Data Patch, I'm interested!
Feel free to comment or suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding before:

```
$modelCustomer->save();
```

The following line:

```
$modelCustomer->setAcmeNlSubscription($acmeNlSubscription);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Sundar. I finally found a solution that I'm posting next.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, but it didn't help me to resolve my problem yet.

I tried that too :

```
public function afterExecute(Save $subject, $result)
    {
        $acmeNlSubscription = $this->request->getParam('acme_nl_subscription') ? (int)$this->request->getParam('acme_nl_subscription') : 0;

        $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomerId();
        $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
        $customer->setData('acme_nl_subscription', $acmeNlSubscription);

        $this->customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);

        return $result;
    }
```

I can't understand why that doesn't work ???